# Why is setInterval() not working in my ES6 code?

Tags: javascript

I have a class named main with a method called `setDate()`. In the constructor method I put the line: `setInterval(main.setDate(), 10000)` and it only runs the initial time the object is instatiated. If I put the line as a tail call in the `setDate()` method, it runs infinitely & breaks the browser session.

Comment: Sorry if this was duplicated. I could not find a similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to pass the `function reference`,

```
setInterval(main.setDate, 10000);
```

You are calling it. So that function will be called and its returning value will be passed as the first parameter to `setInterval`.

You could also achieve the required effect by passing the function call as a string,

```
setInterval("main.setDate()", 10000);
```

But passing string is not recommended as it would be `eval`uated under the hood in window scope.

Comment: Do not pass a string.

Comment: @SLaks Explained it. Thanks for pointing that.